# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method Dependencies() for arguments

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

Full error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method Dependencies() for arguments [build_aewao5k4tyewg69imdynjiuxi$_run_closure1$_closure3@7c332105] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
```

Top level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

   Dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dependencies` (with small d) instead of `Dependencies`

Comment: Can't believe it! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help:)

Comment: @Ezio  can you or anyone please share some info/link on why the character case is an issue? Thank you !!

Comment: gradle is nothing but a groovy script and groovy is a case sensitive language like Java. For example if you type Int in java instead of int, it won't work, same thing is applied here

Answer (score 0):

change Dependencies to dependencies

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```